# How to implement or in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, project and user schemas

User can create multiple projects

The user schema :

```
{
 Name: String, 
 Pass: string, 
}
```

Project schema :

```
{ 
 ProjectName: String,
 members : [ {type: ObjectId, ref : 'user' } ], 
 admin: {type : ObjectId, ref 'user' } 
}
```

I want to get the projects for a particular user
If he is the admin of the project  or if he is a one of the members of a given project
So the user would be eather an admin or a member of the projects

Let's say user1 is member of "project1"
And he is also the admin of "project 2"
So I want to write query to get both project 1 and project 2 in mongoose js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
Project.find({
    $or: [
        // edit { 'members._id': user1.id },
        // edit { 'admin._id': user1.id }
        { 'members': user1.id },
        { 'admin': user1.id }
    ]
});
```

[MongoDB $or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

[Dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I had to write it like the following : Project.find({
    $or: [
        { 'members': user1.id },
        { 'admin': user1.id }
    ]
});